# What can bool type return in C99?

Tags: c, standards, arithmetic-expressions, integer-arithmetic

What is bool guaranteed to return as? Can I rely on a bool type to always be interpreted as 0 or 1? If bool's numerical interpretation isn't reliable in C99 is there a standard where it is? Are there any things I should look out for in LLVM, GCC, or Visual C++ when relying on bool for arithmetic?

Just for example what if I did this:

```
// An example of calculating a possible stride in bytes.
// hasData(), is8bit(), and is16bit() return as bool type

unsigned int stride = object->hasData() * object->size() * 
                      (object->is8bit()  * sizeof(uint8_t) + 
                       object->is16bit() * sizeof(uint16_t));
```

In the example I'm betting on bool type only returning 0 or 1.

Comment: See [6.2.5.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5): *An object declared as type _Bool is large enough to store the values 0 and 1.* and [6.3.1.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.2): *When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.*

Comment: Any practical implementation will make _Bool much larger.  (In practise it will have space to store 0..255).  C guarantees that `unsigned int` has space to hold 65535.  The post is asked a question that is equivalent to asking "am I guaranteed that unsigned int will never evaluate to larger than 65535?"  For unsigned int, the answer is "no".  For _Bool it is "yes".

Comment: Your title says "C99" but your tags include "C++". Which is it?

Comment: If you're having problems then check your headers don't do a `#define bool` or `typedef bool` somewhere ... code that was migrated from C89 might do this instead of including C99's `#include <stdbool.h>`

Comment: @M.M Originally was going to ask this question for C++11 but, forgot to change the tags.

Comment: I'm grateful that I've gotten responses but, a lot of people are citing the macros defined in stdbool.h. Which is great. Thanks guys. But what does that tell me about runtime behavior? @pmg answered the question best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C99 standard requires the compiler to produce `_Bool` values that are either 0 or 1. C++ also has this requirement. No, I don't know the exact page of the standard document that describes this.

Of course, 16 years after the introduction, it's still possible that there are bugs in compilers, and more so if we have a compiler that is, say, 10 years old and wasn't well tested for C99 compatibility when it was produced. But I frequently write code that relies on the compiler producing 0 or 1 from conditional expressions, for example.

Comment: In C, relational operators have always been specified to evaluate to `(int)1` or `(int)0`

Answer (score 5):

> What is bool guaranteed to return as? Can I rely on a bool type to always be interpreted as 0 or 1?

In a strictly conforming program a `_Bool` (or `bool` from `stdbool.h`) expression is guaranteed to be evaluated to either `0` or `1`.

If you get a different value from a `bool` expression it means you are invoking some undefined behavior upstream.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean value of an expression is either `1` (`true`) or `0` (`false`) always and are of type `int` instead of `_Bool`.

#### C99 - 7.16:

> 1. The header `<stdbool.h>` deﬁnes four macros.
> 2. The macro
>
>    - `bool` expands to `_Bool`.
> 3. The remaining three macros are suitable for use in `#if` preprocessing directives. They are
>
>    - `true` : which expands to the **integer constant `1`**,
>    - `false`: which expands to the **integer constant `0`**, and
>    - __bool_true_false_are_defined which expands to the integer constant 1.

Comment: The bolded point could be expounded:  the macros `true` and `false` actually have type `int`, not `_Bool` . In most scenarios this makes no difference but it's worth bearing in mind, e.g. `sizeof(true)` may differ from `sizeof(bool)`

Answer (score 1):

In C++ `bool` is a type which is guaranteed to contain either `true` or `false`.  When converted to `int` (as in your example), these correspond to 1 and 0 respectively.